# Routes.rb vs rack-rewrite vs nginx/apache rewrite rules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have dozens of rewrite rules for legacy URLs from a previous incarnation of my application.
I see three choices:

1. Just add "match" lines in the routes file (config/routes.rb)
2. Use [rack-rewrite](https://github.com/jtrupiano/rack-rewrite)
3. Create Nginx/Apache rewrite rules (Nginx in my case)

I imagine that 3 has better performance than 2, which has better performance than 1.

My questions:

- Is that true?
- If so, how much does it matter?
- Are there other trade-offs I might not have considered?
- Any other options altogether besides those three?

Answer (score 9):

1. Yes, you have the performance order correct.
2. Depends on your site, the traffic, the number of hits on those rewrite rules - in all likelihood the performance matters a lot less than the maintainability.
3. Maintainability - use what you know, and what your developers know.  Apache's rewrite syntax is easy to get wrong, and tends to be quite *Write-Once-Read-Never*.  Nginx's is quite nice, but still a new DSL for you and your devs to learn.  rack-rewrite is the inverse of Apache, it's actually hard to make a mistake because it's so simple (I think it's simpler than `routes.rb`)
4. None worth evaluating.

Comment: This is just about the exact answer I was about to write :) routes is easiest to maintain and performance will be Fine. you can make a 'legacy-rewrites.rb' file in lib and include it in routes.rb, that way it won't clutter up your main app config.