# How do I use regular expressions in a Rails route to make a redirection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, url-rewriting

This attempted rewrite rule in my routes.rb is probably self-explanatory:

```
match "/:user/:photo-thumb.png" => 
      redirect("/%{user}/photos/%{photo}/image?style=thumb"),
      :photo => /[a-zA-Z]+/
```

I want to redirect something like mysite.com/alice/foo-thumb.png to mysite.com/alice/photos/foo/image?style=thumb

The above attempt is wrong though. Any ideas for fixing it?

Comment: Is that last regex a constraint?

Comment: @DGM That was just part of my attempt to get :photo to match the part before the "-thumb".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following worked for me:

```
match "/:user/:photo_thumb.png" => 
      redirect{|p| 
        "/#{p[:user]}/photos/#{p[:photo_thumb].split('-')[0]}/image?style=thumb"
      },
      :constraints => { :photo_thumb => /[a-zA-Z]*\-thumb/ }
```

I'd love to find a simpler way to do it though. (As tadman points out, I may be better off doing this with nginx rewrites. See this related question: [Routes.rb vs rack-rewrite vs nginx/apache rewrite rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5756965/routes-rb-vs-rack-rewrite-vs-nginx-apache-rewrite-rules) )

Comment: Or, without knowing the bigger picture here, take a look at paperclip to handle image attachments...  railscast here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/134-paperclip

Answer (score 3):

You may have more luck with something like this:

```
match "/:user/:photo.png" => 
  redirect("/%{user}/photos/%{photo}/image?style=thumb"),
  :photo => /\w+\-thumb/
```

The route tokens can be confused by having additional content in them.

As a note, this sort of thing is often better handled on the web server level, like Apache, nginx or lighttpd, where redirects won't tie up instances of your Rails stack. Having a large mapping table is not uncommon in applications with significant numbers of legacy links.

Comment: Thanks @tadman! I believe this doesn't quite work in my case because in the rewritten URL where you have %{photo} it needs to not include the "-thumb".

Comment: It looks like you have touched upon a possible fix here, using the block version of `redirect` to do some simple string mangling.