# Rails routes match by regexp

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have routes rule:

```
match '*path' => redirect("/some_scope/%{path}")
```

But I need to apply this only if the current path doesn't start from `/some_scope/`

Comment: Do you need to match literally everything ending with `path` as you've shown above, or do you need to match every path and append `/some_scope/` to it if it doesn't already have that scope?

Comment: For example, do you mean to do `match '*' => redirect("/some_scope/%{whatever_was_matched}")`

Comment: >> do you mean to do match '*' => redirect("/some_scope/%{whatever_was_matched}")
yes, I mean this

Answer (score 1):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#dynamic-segments

[How do I use regular expressions in a Rails route to make a redirection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799024/how-do-i-use-regular-expressions-in-a-rails-route-to-make-a-redirection)

Those two should be able to help you solve your problem. It would be nice if you gave us real code, so I can determine exactly what you're trying to do, because it seems like you might not even need a regex in this case.

If you're trying to do what I think you're trying to do... that is apply a scope to a path if it doesn't already contain that scope, you would be better off doing `before_filters` in your `ApplicationController`. That is:

```
before_filter :check_locale

protected

def check_locale
  redirect_to "/some_scope#{request.path_info}" if not request.path_info =~ /^\/some_scope\//
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
DEFAULT_PATH_SCOPE = "/my_scope"

default_scope_constraint = ->(request) do
  !request.path.starts_with?(DEFAULT_PATH_SCOPE)
end

constraints(default_scope_constraint) do
  match '*path' => redirect("#{DEFAULT_PATH_SCOPE}/%{path}")
end
```