# Rails routing image paths via regular expressions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have put some images in a folder named `i` inside the `public` folder of my rails application source.

[image]

Now what I want to accomplish is, if some one tries calling the images with any extra functions as well, it should return the image url.

For eg.,

If someone tries to access these images as shown below:

```
 "http://192.168.193.102:3000/i/c77b5f55-b09d-48aa-8301-90ab73810332.jpg/overlay=c0643653-8f3c-4867-adce-1ce25fc0b8a8_1"
```

or

```
"http://192.168.193.102:3000/i/c77b5f55-b09d-48aa-8301-90ab73810332.jpg/160x224f"
```

or

```
"http://192.168.193.102:3000/i/c77b5f55-b09d-48aa-8301-90ab73810332.jpg/*<anything>"
```

it should still return the url as shown below

```
"http://192.168.193.102:3000/i/c77b5f55-b09d-48aa-8301-90ab73810332.jpg"
```

Is it possible to do that in Rails. 
If yes, please give me some pointers on how to do the same.

How I temporarily tried to solve this is by adding the below lines to routes.rb :

```
get '/i/c77b5f55-b09d-48aa-8301-90ab73810332.jpg/overlay=c0643653-8f3c-4867-adce-1ce25fc0b8a8_1', to: redirect('/i/c77b5f55-b09d-48aa-8301-90ab73810332.jpg')
get '/i/6f9cbd8f-4a63-4e93-ab4b-3e7a2ee48ef7.jpg/overlay=c0643653-8f3c-4867-adce-1ce25fc0b8a8_1', to: redirect('/i/6f9cbd8f-4a63-4e93-ab4b-3e7a2ee48ef7.jpg')
get '/i/06e5cdd5-bd9c-4850-b9df-b04201477d03.jpg/overlay=c0643653-8f3c-4867-adce-1ce25fc0b8a8_1', to: redirect('/i/06e5cdd5-bd9c-4850-b9df-b04201477d03.jpg')
get '/i/e31a5e5c-1833-41c7-8148-5346f291774d.jpg/overlay=c0643653-8f3c-4867-adce-1ce25fc0b8a8_1', to: redirect('/i/e31a5e5c-1833-41c7-8148-5346f291774d.jpg')
```

I will end up adding more of these in my routes and it is not going to look good in the future.

If I can get a regular expression based logic, it will be really helpful.

Comment: Would this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799024/how-do-i-use-regular-expressions-in-a-rails-route-to-make-a-redirection ?

Comment: Couldn't understand much. I am new to rails. Have very basic idea in routes.

Comment: Your images are in the public folder which means that when the request for one of them is made through your web server (apache / nginx) the later will find the image and serve it directly, bypassing rails. So rails is pretty much useless in this context.

Comment: @charlysisto I am using Thin web server in my development environment. I dint understand what you meant by 'the later will find the image and serve it directly, bypassing rails'

Comment: It meant : "your web server will find the image and serve it directly..." Maybe what your asking for is possible in development mode (in a rack middleware) but it would be useless since it won't work in production mode. What you probably need to find is some apache/nginx rule (out of my scope unfortunately)